# Exclude single library from GoLand index (autocompletion)

Tags: goland

GoLand by default indexes the library defined by the `go.mod` which is great. This happens because one of the libraries is pulling an indirect dependency and this gets indexed. Is it possible to exclude from autocompletion/auto-import a single indirect dependency?

For example, when I type `return errors.New(buffer.String())` the IDE automatically imports `"github.com/pkg/errors"` instead of `errors`.

```
import "github.com/pkg/errors"
// import "errors" << This is what I want
func myFunc() error{
    return errors.New(buffer.String())
}
```

```
module actual-experience.com/digital-user

require (
    github.com/coreos/bbolt v1.3.0
    github.com/davecgh/go-spew v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/georgeok/go-httpstat v0.0.0-20180624225026-6e05174a0aaf
    github.com/google/gopacket v1.1.14
    github.com/pkg/errors v0.8.0 // indirect
    ....
)
```

Comment: When there are two or more packages named `errors` the IDE will not import automatically a package to avoid situations like this. Either here or on an issue in our bug tracker, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/Go, please describe all the steps to reproduce the issue, including how you type the ` return... ` line and what do you choose from the auto-complete pop-up. Ignoring an import is not a correct solution for this problem.

Comment: When you type that’s the case, I agree. One way to reproduce it is to copy and paste code and the IDE does the imports automatically